# XmlHttpRequest error: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin despite "header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');"

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest, same-origin-policy

Hy there,

I'm implementing a bookmarklet that needs to post some XMLHttpRequests to a php-script which is done via JQuery.

Basically this is looking something like this (just simple examples...):

Javascript:

```
$.post('https://www.myserver.com/script.php').always(function(data) {
    console.warn('data:', data);
}
```

script.php:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

$res["isSession"] = false;
echo json_encode($res);
```

At first this wasn't working at all because of the null-origin but after I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4968221/1273551) I added the "header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');" line.

With this line it's at least working when i execute the script on a locally installed Apache.

Unfortunately as soon as i try to execute it on my online site that is located on a shared host it doesn't work but gives me "XmlHttpRequest error: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin" error message.

On the shared host it's also Apache running. Could this be caused by some Apache-config? If yes, which one?

What else could be the problem and how can i resolve it?

Thanks

ps.: If i explicitly use jsonp as datatype for the jquery-post it's working, but therefore I'd have to rewrite some php files and some other javascripts that use them too. Therefore I'd like to avoid this option if possible...

---

edit:
I just found out that the php file on the online server is inside a directory that is "locked" with a htaccess-file. If i move the php file to a directory that is accessible for everyone i don't get the mentioned error message.

Does anybody now how i can circumvent this problem? Putting the php file to an publicly accessible directory wouldn't be exactly my preferred option...

Comment: Did you request the file from a local file or from a local web server? I guess it won't work from local file because it won't have a valid origin

Comment: I always request the file from a web server. So it's always a http-link and no file-link...
When i request it from the locally installed Apache Webserver, everything works fine, as soon as i request it from an online available Apache Webserver it's not working anymore...

Comment: I don't mean the location of the requested file ... I mean the location of the file with the jQuery code requesting the remote script.php

Comment: The javascript file that posts the request is also located on the webserver.

Comment: I just recognized another thing:
If i open the bookmarklet from e.g. google.com, the error message says "Origin http://www.google.at is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin." instead of "Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."...